# In Python how to do Correlation between Multiple Columns more than 2 variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, correlation

I have a Pandas Dataframe like so:

```
id    cat1    cat2    cat3    num1    num2
1     0       WN      29      2003    98
2     1       TX      12      755     76
3     0       WY      11      845     32
4     1       IL      19      935     46
```

I want to find out the correlation between `cat1` and column `cat3`, `num1` and `num2`
or between `cat1` and `num1` and `num2`
or between `cat2` and `cat1, cat3, num1, num2`

When I use `df.corr()` it gives Correlation between all the columns in the dataframe, but I want to see Correlation between just these selective columns detailed above.

How do I do that in Python pandas?

A Thousand thanks in advance for your answers.

Comment: `df[['Cat1','cat3']].corr()`, etc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I tried the following and it worked :

```
features1=['cat1','cat2','cat3']
features2=['Cat1', 'Cat2','num1','num2']

df[features1].corr()
df[features2].corr()
```

A good way to select the columns based on the need when you have a very high number of variables in your dataset.

Comment: You don't need to call `list`, your argument is already a list.