# Correletion between coeffecions in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, keras

I have small problem and i don't know how to resolve it. I using Python and pandas and numpy library to make correlation between coeffecions. Data are place in dataframe object. To count the correlation using corrcoef(...) function. This function count the correlation between one to one variables, but i want to count correlation between many to one.
For example:

A | B | C | D

---|---|---|---

1 | 8 | 6 | 0

5 | 9 | 5 | 3

3 | 0 | 1 | 2

Standard correlation is counting between A and C , or C and B or B and D columns. But I want correlation between A,C to D or B,C,D to A .
How can i to this in Python? Mayby tensorflow or keras library.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42128462/in-python-how-to-do-correlation-between-multiple-columns-more-than-2-variables) could be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could just print it out with `df.corr()`

Personally, I would print out a heatmap to make it easier to analyze

```
import seaborn as sns

fig = sns.heatmap(df.corr(), annot=True)
fig.show()
```

Comment: OK. But this is two dimension correletion between for example A and B. I need multidimension correlation for example A,C to D.

Comment: What does the correlation of A,C to D mean?

Comment: This mean i need correlation two  columns A,C (as all) to one column D

Comment: What is the math operation You mean as correlation A,C to D? Person, Spearman and Kendall coeffitions are defined between two params, not three.